# Simplest angularjs page not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am watching a [video](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/angularjs-in-60-ish-minutes-the-ebook) to learn angularjs. I used CDN link for including angularJs

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"/>
    </head>
    <body ng-init="names=['shan', 'amit', 'vaibhav']">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="pname in names">
            {{pname}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have no other file. That's the simplest piece of code I have and on browser I see blank page. What's wrong in this?

Comment: Voting to close as a typographical error; people are just spamming the same answer over and over

Comment: I agree, I can see that as well. Crazy people

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put an `ng-app` attribute on the `html` tag:

```
<html ng-app>
```

And close your `script` tag (it's not self-closing)

http://jsfiddle.net/g02ket0t/

Comment: curious to know, why `ng-app` is required? Is it something angularJs framework searches to initialize angularJs script?

Comment: @ShantanuGupta -- Yes, it's required to bootstrap the app

Comment: I don't understand why people keep posting duplicate answers even after looking that all of their points have been covered in one answer :(. I wish there could have been a way to close those answers.

Answer (score 5):

Fix the script line:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why this? I am using `/`

Comment: Cannot self close a script tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Answer (score -2):

You can also use data-ng-, instead of ng-, if you want to make your page HTML valid.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-init="names=['shan', 'amit', 'vaibhav']">
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="pname in names">{{pname}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You're missing the closing  tag. Also add the ng-app attribute in the html tag to link to your app.

Answer (score -2):

- Complete Script tag
- Use ng-app attribute.

```html
  <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app ng-init="names=['shan', 'amit', 'vaibhav']">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="pname in names">
            {{pname}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```